# How to name a dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, coding-style, naming-conventions

Are there any conventions / guidelines for naming associative arrays (e.g. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`) in .NET?

For example, is there a better way to name `dict` in:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Foo, Bar>();
```

Some names I've used / seen:

```
foosToBars
mapFromFooToBar
barsByFoo
barsForFoos
```

I've also seen some types in the BCL choosing 'nicer' sounding names that don't directly reveal what the key and value are supposed to represent, such as in [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287075#Y739).

How about for multimaps (e.g. `ILookup<TKey, TElement>`)?

**EDIT**:

Perhaps my example was slightly poor; I didn't mean to focus on the *types* of the key and value.

How about if it was:

```
// key = Name of person, value = Age of person
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

With the samples updated to:

```
namesToAges
mapFromNameToAge
agesByName
agesForNames
```

Comment: I'd go for `barsByFoo`, as the `Foo`s act as an index here. A `Dictionary<string, Person>` would then simply be `peopleByName`.

Comment: I had `keys` and their `counts`. I just named it `keyCounts`. Not generic  generic rule though...

Answer (score 13):

I'd try to follow the example you linked to, where you don't name the dictionary after what it *contains* but you name it for what it's *for*. It doesn't take long for someone to determine that "dict" is a dictionary that maps `Foo` keys to `Bar` values, but what i'd want to know is why you're doing that.

Comment: Agreed - Modern intellisense makes it trivial to figure out what it is, but it's often quite a bit more difficult to figure out why it is...

Comment: Great point : "name it for what it's for". I chose a bad example that unnecessarily focused on the *types* of the key and value though; I've updated the question. My bad.

Comment: I agree. `Dictionary<int, User> ageIndex;`  says it all.